# Spring-Boot 2.3.1 -Dspring-boot.run.arguments not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-2

I have been using mvn spring-boot:run command with -Dspring-boot.run.arguments to pass arguments/variables to our spring-boot application, ex:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--jwt.validateExp=false,--jwt.skipValidation=true
```

And in the application, I used to read the argument value using annotation: @Value("${jwt.skipValidation}"). This was working fine with spring-boot 2.2.1.

When I upgraded to spring-boot 2.3.1, this stopped working. Any suggestion?

Comment: Check out https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.1.RELEASE/maven-plugin/reference/html/#run-example-application-arguments

Comment: Hi @SimonMartinelli, As per the maven-plugin documentation, I have tried following, but that also didn't work: mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="jwt.validateExp=false jwt.skipValidation=true"

Comment: A guess in the wild. Can you try -Drun.arguments

Comment: This worked:   -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--jwt.validateExp=false --jwt.skipValidation=true"         Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: where is this in their changelog notes? ? ? ? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Changing --jwt.validateExp=false,--jwt.skipValidation=true to "--jwt.validateExp=false --jwt.skipValidation=true", did the trick for me.

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--jwt.validateExp=false --jwt.skipValidation=true"
```

So placed double quotes ("") around the arguments, and provided space in place of comma (,).

Answer (score 3):

I'm using spring.boot 2.4.2 and to solve this, i separated the arguments with withe-space and put the values between double quotes.

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--jwt.validateExp=false --jwt.skipValidation=true"
```